# Ошибка в INSERT запросе

Tags: c#, mysql

Есть следующая ошибка

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Return(idBook, librarycardnumber, idIssue, fio, nameBook, dateIssue, dataReturn)' at line 1"
```

Вот сам код

```
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
        string query2 = "INSERT INTO Return(idBook, librarycardnumber, idIssue, fio, nameBook, dateIssue, dataReturn) " + "Values('" + txtIdBook.Text + "', '" + txtIdReader.Text + "', '" + txtIdIssue.Text + "', '" + lblFullName.Text + "', '" + lblBookName.Text + "', '" + time + "', '" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "')";
        MySqlConnection MyCon2 = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        MySqlCommand command2 = new MySqlCommand(query2, MyCon2);
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter2 = new MySqlDataAdapter(command2);
        DataTable table2 = new DataTable();
        adapter2.Fill(table2);
        MessageBox.Show("Книга видана");
        this.Close();
```

Как мне ее исправить?

Comment: Return - резервированное слово. Именно по поводу неправильного его использования сервер и возмущён. Переименуйте таблицу или квотируйте имя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнем с того, что строка `query2="INSERT INTO Return(..."` определяет команду на добавление новой строки в таблицу:

`MySqlCommand command2 = new MySqlCommand(query2, MyCon2);`

Но конструктор `MySqlDataAdapter(MySqlCommand)` ждет команды "SELECT" см. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDataAdapter.htm

Поэтому Вы получаете сообщение об ошибки в синтаксисе.

Резюме Вы должны для адаптера определить требуемую строку "SELECT" и использовать ее при конструировании адаптера.

P.S.:

По поводу добавлений - поискал в Интернет - мне кажется, что ссылки ниже содержат все, что Вам нужно:

https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/MySql.Data.MySqlClient/MySqlDataAdapter/Fill/php-mysqldataadapter-fill-method-examples.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652978/parameterized-query-for-mysql-with-c-sharp

Comment: @Владимир я пишу ответ на колене с планшета в метро. Если Вам что-то не понятно, то я дополню ответ, но Вам придется подождать, пока я не окажусь рядом с нормальным компьютером. Советы по поводу параметров в командной строке, которые Вам дали в другом ответе - абсолютно правильные, но это я тоже распишу позже.

Comment: спасибо, я уже разобрался. Но я бы был очень благодарен, если б вы показали то как должен выглядеть этот кусок кода в идеале.

Comment: Нет проблем, но Вам придется подождать, когда я доберусь до избушки в лесу с компьютером :)

Answer (score 2):

Не правильно так делать выполнение запроса.

Вы должны создать запрос с параметрами, а далее ему передать аргументы.

В том виде, который вы написали запрос обломается, если в текстовых полях будут какие-нибудь спец. символа, например `'`.

Собственно, скорее всего это у вас и произошло.